# Difficulty showing function output in GUI with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to python and am attempting to write code to return tax payable from an inputted gross salary figure.

I have got to the point where my code is successfully running: Gui window appearing, functions running without error. However, I seem to be unable to show my function output in the GUI window itself.

I have attempted assigning a variable to a label to show the output on the same screen to the side of the button widget, and also creating a new function to show the output in a new window once this button has been clicked. Both have been unsuccessful.

I have attached a relevant snippets of my code below - as the full script would not run for others without login details. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Button:

```
#Widgets
    Button(enter_details ,text='Tax', 
           width=19,command=incometax).grid(row=4,sticky=N,padx=10)
```

Function:

```
def incometax():  
    result = float(grosssalary.get())

    #variables
    global tax

    bands = [0, 12570, 50270, 150000, inf]
    rates = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.45]

    tax = 0.0

    for i in range(len(bands)-1):
      amount = min(bands[i+1]-bands[i] , max(0, result - bands[i]))
      payable = amount * rates[i]

     tax = tax + payable

     if result<bands[i+1]:
        break

     return tax
```

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? You're overwriting the variables each time through the loop, not accumulating anything, so the final result is just from the last iteration.

Comment: Your function just returns a value, which is not used for anything. It should update the widget that you want to display in.

Comment: Thanks! My issue is displaying this function output in the GUI itself, do I need to assign the output value to a new widget?

Comment: Yes, of course you do. You can use a `FloatVar` that's associated with the widget.

Comment: I have already attempted to do so using the following code: tax = Label(enter_details, text='', textvariable=taxtext).grid(row=4, sticky=E ,padx=10). the textvariable was previously defined but still no output showed

Comment: Did you add `taxtext.set(str(tax))` to the function?

Comment: I had done so without the 'str', think that might be it working now though. Thanks for the  help